# Creating/Getting/Extracting multiple data frames from python dictionary of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a python dictionary with keys as dataset names and values as the entire data frames themselves, see the dictionary dict below

[Dictionary of Dataframes ]

One way id to write all the codes manually like below:

```
csv = dict['csv.pkl']
csv_emp = dict['csv_emp.pkl']    
csv_emp_yr= dict['csv_emp_yr.pkl']    
emp_wf=dict['emp_wf.pkl']
emp_yr_wf=dict['emp_yr_wf.pkl']
```

But this will get very inefficient with more number of datasets.
Any help on how to get this done over a loop?

Comment: Firstly, don't name your dictionary `dict`, use `d` or `dict_` instead. Secondly, what is the purpose of extracting our dataframes to specific variables? You can always modify dictionary values (the dataframes within your dictionary) directly.

Answer (score 0):

**Although I would not recommend this method but you can try this:**

```
import sys
this = sys.modules[__name__] # this is now your current namespace
for key in dict.keys():
    setattr(this, key, dict[key])
```

Now you can check new variables made with names same as keys of dictionary.

globals() has risk as it gives you what the namespace is currently pointing to but this can change and so modifying the return from globals() is not a good idea

**List can also be used like (limited usecases):**

```
dataframes = []
for key in dict.keys():
    dataframes.append(dict[key])
```

Still this is your choice, both of the above methods have some limitations.